# How to create a copy of object of class with map?

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, clone, immutability

I have a class

```
public class student 
{
  private int Id;
  private map<String , String> subjects;
  private map<String , String> teachers;
  private String name; 
}
```

Let me explain the scenario more clearly . I have a function which is taking Student object as a parameter . This function is being called from various other classes . Now in this function I am creating seven threads to perform some computation based on the student input object . Though there is no modification of the student object presently . Still I want to keep it safe by passing in copies of the student object so that if anyone later on modifies the input in any of the threads It should not modify other threads.

So how can i create a new object for the map ?
Also another solution I could try is to create this class as immutable but even then the map is a problem .
How to make map immutable .

Comment: If a thread modifies a map, do you need to reconcile all the copies later? That's a hard problem.

Comment: You can just return a copy of the map from the getter method? `new HashMap()`. Oh, and you want the threads to be able to modify `Student` instance? That's going to affect all other threads.

Comment: the requirements seem unclear. do you want these threads to modify the object or not? If you can solve your problem in a way that keeps your objects immutable that's the easiest and most straightforward way, I don't get why "the map is a problem" here. maybe [Java: how to make a private field Map immutable within a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19125160/217324) is related?

Comment: Why would 7 threads be manipulating the same student simultaneously? If you make the student object immutable, then each of these threads would have their own copies (which they couldn't modify); how would this help? Could you add more code that explains the bigger picture?

Comment: The threads could modify the object 
So I want them to have their own copy of object .
However just having the instance of Student class how do I create a copy of the map as I do not know whether it has been initialised as a hashmap , treemap , linkedhashmap etc.

Comment: You don't need to know about the implementation details of the map. If you need a copy, you can use the [copy constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap(java.util.Map)) of `HashMap`. But what are you doing with the 7 different copies of the student object?

Comment: If i use a copy constructor of hashmap I will create a copy of object whcih will be a hashmap 
What if I had a linked hashmap and then copied it using hashmap constuctor.
In that case it is wrong .

Comment: The variables are _declared_ with the `Map` interface type so the program should behave the same regardless of what `Map` implementation is used. That's the whole point in coding against interfaces. Ignoring this, shouldn't you know how the maps are initialized in the first place (if you've written that class)?

Comment: Let me explain the scenario more clearly .
I have a function which is taking Student object as a parameter .
This function is being called from various other classes .
Now in this function I am creating seven threads to perform some computation based on the student input object .
Though there is no modification of the student object presently .
Still I want to keep it safe by passing in copies of the student object so that if anyone later on modifies the input in any of the threads 
It should not modify other threads.

Comment: Now while copying say the map was initialsed as a linkedHashMap and the send to my function. Since linkedhashmap is sorted there can be a case where some thread is doing computatioin based on the sorted assumption .
If I now create a copy as hashmap it will not be sorted which will break the logic ahead .

Comment: Please edit the question with this information and also add the code for your function. In any case, no-one can/should make an assumption of element-ordering if the variable has been declared as a plain `Map`. The interface contract does not define how elements are ordered.

Answer (score 1):

If the threads **have to** manipulate the object:

- create copies of the objects and maps, for example by using `Map<String, String> subjects = new HashMap<>()`
- if your objects are becoming more complex use a copy-library (like dozer) or use serialization (like jaxb)

If the threads **do not have to** manipulate the object:

- just pass the same instance to all threads
- for safety you could make the maps immutable with the methods in the `Collections` class

By the way:

- consider storing lists of `Subject` objects and `Teacher` objects. This makes your code easier to extend, than using maps.

Comment: I cannot make a copying like this Map<String, String> subjects = new HashMap<>() . 
You donot know may be the map has been initialised as a treemap or may be a linked hashmap .
That is my main concern .

Comment: Also in the second case you are saying if I have not to manipulate 
I can make the map immutable with collection method
could you explain this in detail ?